# Call Image.getSize from Outside Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to call Image.getSize from a general js file that exports a function but I am getting the error

> Cannot read property 'getSize' of undefined

Seems like Image is coming up as undefined. How do I define it I though importing Image from react-navigation would do the trick but unfortunately not.

How would I fix this error?

**imageFunctions.js**

```
import { Image } from 'react-navigation';

module.exports = {

checkBlankImages(url){

 Image.getSize(url, () => {
        return "Pic is good"
     },
     () => {
       return "Pic is not good"
    }
  )
 }

}
```

**HomePage.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default class MatchesPage extends Component{

  console.log(functions.checkBlankImages(url))

}
```

Comment: `Image` is defined in `react-native` not `react-navigation`

Comment: Are you creating a function to check if the image it's good or not? or to do something with the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image` is defined in `react-native` not `react-navigation`.  Change your import to:

```
import { Image } from 'react-native'
```

Comment: Yeah now thinking about it that makes sense and that worked! What a simple mistake thank you.